# create a column in a data table based on changes on another column in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

table .For this data table I have a column for balance and I want to create a column based on changes in balance column. 
To mock up the data

```
set.seed(1)
zzz  <- data.table(name=rep(c('x','y','z'),100),
                   balance=sample(100:300,100,replace = T), key = "name")
```

Now I have changed few datas to mock up what I want to do

```
zzz[5:7,2] <-238
zzz[20:22,2]<- 204
```

as I want to make some balance same in order to show what I intend to achieve ,

Now my code to achive a flag for change in balance for each name is as follows

```
cur_bal <- -99999999

bal_change_flag <- function(x){
  #cur_bal <- -99999999
  flag <- 1
  if(x !=cur_bal){
    flag <- 1
  }else {flag <- 0}
  cur_bal <<-x 
  return (flag)
}
zzz[,code:=lapply(balance,bal_change_flag),name]
```

Now I expect `zzz[5:7,2:3,with=F]`as

```
   balance code
1:     238    1
2:     238    0
3:     238    0
```

but I get it as

```
   balance code
1:     238    1
2:     238    1
3:     238    1
```

the function works fine if I dont group it by name but fails to achieve the same when I group it by name .Please advise :) thanks

```
> zzz[,code:=lapply(balance,bal_change_flag)]
> zzz[5:7,2:3,with=F]
   balance code
1:     238    1
2:     238    0
3:     238    0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but I guess you're trying to create a flag for whether the balance changed in each row?

I think you've made a poor example. Perhaps this is better:

```
set.seed(3040)
data <- data.table(name = rep(c("x","y","z"), 100),
                   balance = sample(3, 100, TRUE), key = "name")
```

I think what you're after is as simple as:

```
data[ , code := balance == shift(balance, fill = TRUE), by = name]
```

With output:

```
> data
     name balance  code
  1:    x       2  TRUE #first obs. within group always TRUE thanks to 'fill'
  2:    x       3  TRUE #3 != 2
  3:    x       1  TRUE #1 != 3
  4:    x       1 FALSE #1 == 1
  5:    x       2  TRUE
 ---                   
296:    z       3  TRUE
297:    z       3 FALSE
298:    z       2  TRUE
299:    z       1  TRUE
300:    z       1 FALSE
```

You could force this to be `1` and `0` by using `as.integer` or `+`, but why?

Comment: Thanks for the great example and answer ,yes you are correct that I made a poor example but thats the best  which I came up with at that time ,I need this as 1,0 because of ease in numeric computation as I am going to store this in a Dimensional table .Thanks for your patience in understanding my question and for your answer

Comment: @Bg1850 whenever it's needed, it will automatically be coerced to an integer. See `?TRUE::Details` Either way is fine, though.

Comment: Any idea why the function does not work while grouping ,although I have solved the problem with the solutions provided but this will bug me unless I got an explanation .

Answer (score 1):

Dplyr is much more intuitive and easy in my opinion. Using it here, you can do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
> zzz  <- data.frame(name=rep(c('x','y','z'),100),balance=sample(100:300,100,replace = T))
> zzz <- arrange(zzz, name)
> zzz[5:7,2] <-238
> zzz[20:22,2]<- 204
> zzz <- zzz %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(code = as.numeric(balance != lag(balance)))
> zzz[5:7, ]
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
Groups: name [1]

    name balance  code
  (fctr)   (dbl) (dbl)
1      x     238     1
2      x     238     0
3      x     238     0
> zzz[20:22, ]
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
Groups: name [1]

    name balance  code
  (fctr)   (dbl) (dbl)
1      x     204     1
2      x     204     0
3      x     204     0
>
```

Comment: +1 ,I have never used dplyr and have to learn it ,which is why I would prefer a soln with a data.table approach :) thanks nevertheless

Comment: Hi How do I make the 1st entry for each group as 1 ,like for example in this piece I want the first as 1 not NA
`1       x     153          NA
2       x     282           1
3       x     289           1
4       x     112           1
5       x     238           1
6       x     238           0
7       x     238           0
8       x     142           1`

Comment: `as.integer` is better than `as.numeric`. Try `+(balance != lag(balance))` for some extra spice in your life ;-)

Comment: @Bg1850: you can mutate the values by substituting NAs for 1. zzz$code[is.na(zzz$code)] <- 1;

Comment: Yep I have added this line to achieve this  
`%>% mutate(flag_change=ifelse(is.na(flag_change),1,flag_change)`

Comment: @Bg1850 and thus `dplyr` proves, once again, it's ugly and unintuitive.